# Why is the verb after the words “better” and “rather” always singular (no s)?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, pronouns

I don’t know what word type these belong to (are they adverbs?). I notice that the verbs after these two words are always singular verbs even though the pronoun is a singular pronoun.

The following is an example.

We better ask.” is correct grammar as expected since the pronoun is plural. The verb must not end with s.

However, “She better asks.” is not correct grammar even though the pronoun is singular. I thought verbs following singular third-person pronouns end with s.

“She better ask.” is the correct one.

I don’t understand because “She asks.” is correct, while “She ask.” is not correct. If so, why is “She better asks.” not correct, and “She better ask.” is correct?

Why do words such as “better”,  “rather” change this convention?

What I find even more confusing is that words like “never” and “always” do not change the convention. “She never ask.” is not correct, while “She never asks.” is correct.

I could be wrong, but don’t these words have the same word type as “rather” and “better”? It’s just that “rather” and “better” is for suggestion/recommendation while “never” and “always” is for frequency.

Comment: You're confusing the grammar. _Better_  between subject and a verb is short for the idiom _had better._ This contracts to /d/ in front of _better_ and then drops the /d/ in ordinary speech. So _She better not go_ is really _She had better not go_, and there's no inflection on the infinitive. _Rather_ is short for _would rather_, in different contexts but with the same result. Probly this is better addressed in ELL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Had better" — what is the meaning of this grammatically?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/had-better-what-is-the-meaning-of-this-grammatically)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELU. I think your question might do better on [ELL](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour). However, before you do that, make sure you check all your sentences. they are not all correct. Good luck.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said. So *“We better ask.” is **not really** correct grammar as expected*, since it lacks the "active" verb *[we] **had** [better do whatever it would be better for us to do]*.